# Network Aborted Error while login using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to login through API, which is working fine in Postman and Android app but it is giving error in my webpage.

The username which I enetered in data is acceptable in android app and postman.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mUrl = "http://18.218.238.174/kuru-service/oauth/token";

  $("#loginBtn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: mUrl,
      data: {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "mak",
        "password": "1234"
      },
      dataType: "jsonp",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic a3VydS1pb3MtYXgitBwOmt1cnUtc2VydmljZQ==",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function(data, errorThrown) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: My guess is the [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue.

Comment: Likely to be a cross-origin issue

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a cross-origin call from your browser. You can make a jsonp request though. Below is a sample code which you can use.

```js
call_ajax = function(options){
    var data_str = '', url_str = '';
    if (!options) {
 alert('Please pass ajax parameters');
 return false;
    }
    if (!options.url){
       alert('Please pass server url to call');
       return false;
    }

    /* Assign onload/success and onerror/error functions */
    onload_fn = (typeof options.success == 'function') ? options.success : function(){};
    onerror_fn = (typeof options.error == 'function') ? options.error : function(){};

    /* convert data dict to url parameters string */
    if (options.data){
 if ( typeof options.data == 'object'){
     for (key in options.data){
  if (options.data[key]){
      data_str = data_str + '&' + key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(options.data[key]);
  }
     }
 } else if (typeof options.data == 'string'){
     data_str = '&' + options.data;
 }
    }
    /* get final url having url parameters string */
    url_str = (options.url.indexOf('?') > 0) ? options.url + data_str : options.url + '?' + data_str.slice(1);

    /* add script tag with all values */
    loadScript(url_str, onload_fn, onerror_fn);
};

loadScript = function(src, onload, onerror) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    if (script.readyState){
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
 var state = this.readyState;
 if (state === 'loaded' || state === 'complete') {
     script.onreadystatechange = null;
     onload();
     }
        };
    }
   else{
    script.onload = onload;
   }
    script.onerror = onerror;
    head.appendChild(script);
};


call_ajax({
      url: "http://18.218.238.174/kuru-service/oauth/token",
      data: {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "mak",
        "password": "1234"
      },
      success: success_fn,
      error: error_fn
    });
```